# curl command giving "no SOAPAction header!" error

Tags: curl, wsdl

I am trying to run the following curl command but i am getting error shown below:

**command:**

```
curl -H "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8" \
-H "SOAPAction:" \
-d @amit.xml -X POST http://server-ip:8200/axis/services/SOAPRequestHandler
```

**Error:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <soapenv:Body>
  <soapenv:Fault>
   <faultcode xmlns:ns1="http://xml.apache.org/axis/">ns1:Client.NoSOAPAction</faultcode>
<faultstring>no SOAPAction header!</faultstring>
   <detail>
    <ns2:hostname xmlns:ns2="http://xml.apache.org/axis/">stsosctwb10</ns2:hostname>
   </detail>
  </soapenv:Fault>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I read through several articles on how to fix this but nothing is helping. In the wsdl file, the soapAction field is also empty. Below is the wsdl file contents as well:

```
 <wsdl:operation name="processSync">

         <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction=""/>
```

Could you please guide me on what could be wrong with my command?

Comment: what are you trying to get from this line: "-H "SOAPAction:" \" ? Doesnt it indicate that is where the problem is? try using this: http://wsdlbrowser.com/ to test your WSDL

Comment: As per the man page for curl command, -H option is to add a header. So i am using this option to add a header "SOAPAction". Also the wsdl is hosted on a client network so i cannot use SOAP UI or wsdlbrowser to test. I have to login to a server from which the connectivity is there & there i execute the curl command.

Answer (score 3):

curl has a special syntax for headers without value using a semicolon, see [cURL man page](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-H):

> *If you send the custom header with no-value then its header must be terminated with a semicolon, such as -H "X-Custom-Header;" to send "X-Custom-Header:"*

However, specifying `-H "SOAPAction;"` still ends up in a *no SOAPAction header!* message when I post a message to my Axis Web Service. It works with any character like `-H "SOAPAction:;"` or `-H "SOAPAction:foo"`.

Make also sure that your XML is valid.

Answer (score -1):

There to specify de SoapAction :

curl --header "Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8" --header "SOAPAction: ACTION_YOU_WANT_TO_CALL" --data @FILE_NAME URL_OF_THE_SOAP_WEB_SERVICE_ENDPOINT

Example:
curl --header "Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8" --header "SOAPAction:urn:my:service-interaction:soap:some-action" --data @soap_envelope.txt http://192.168.1.1:8080/myservice